# Change Linq to SQL DataContext classname after renaming dbml

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql, datacontext, rename

When I've created Linq to SQL classes in VS2010 resulting in a .dbml file and I change the name of that .dbml file, how can I rename the corresponding DataContext name?

I've got for example **Sample1.dbml**, so a class is generated with the name **Sample1DataContext**.
After I rename the dbml file to **AnotherName.dbml**, the datacontext is still called **Sample1DataContext**. Is there a way to update this manually? The only solution I use is creating a new dbml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have two choice :

1) open your dbml file and change the name in property and change all calls of this class manually or

2) change it from the designer and let it change all calls in the other classes by updating reference name